# standardising an array of vectors

Tags: java, math, vector, normalization

I have an `ArrayList` of lists of vectors.
Each list of vectors has three elements with an undefined amount of vectors i.e

```
x,y,z
x1,y1,z1
....N....
xN,yN,zN
```

But each list I have varies in length 'N' I was just wondering what would be a standard for making them all the same length 'N'. Initially I tried a sparse sampling approach but that didnt work as I miss alot of data and I need to keep as much data as possible. Are there any other methods?

Comment: Your data is broken. How would you know which datapoints are missing? You can't. The data is useless. From where do you get those Arrays? I suspect "0" simply being ignored when creating the arrays resulting in different Nx, Ny, Nz ... perhaps?

Comment: @Fildor no its not broken or ignoring numbers. Just i have images converted to vectors where, each image is a different size so the reason the data changes so much is because i set 'xN' and 'yN' to be the the x and y position of a pixel and 'zN' to be the greyscale value. So as the pictures are different/ some are modified the data varies in length. I.e one image might contain 2000 vectors(the x,y,z) while another will contain only around 1500(x,y,z) vectors. So im wondering is there a better way to standardise the data set without losing as much data when doing sparse sampling?

Comment: Ah, ok. That's different. So the three dimensions are always the same length, but not between two images ...

Comment: Alright then, how to "normalize" depends heavily on what you are doing. You could scale them to a predefined size. But you are introducing error doing so, of course. But if they are pictures of them same scale and distance but only have different margins around an object, you might want to crop instead of scale ... can you follow me?

Comment: @Fildor Ya i understand and thought of this myself but Ive close to 5000 images and that would mean manual editing.Also Ive been given the vector data not the images(its a dataset for a project to do with machine learning) Id have to redraw all the images plotting pixels and this is really not an option due to time constraints.I tried finding the longest vector file and in the others appending 0's/random digits(To make it 'equal' length) but that throws off my precision worse than expected(And I expected it to be pretty bad).I guess i have to bite the bullet and try recrop them to be equal

Comment: Welcome to image processing ... do you have any further information about the images? Like width,height,resolution etc? With only the plain data it will be pretty hard to come up with any sort of "normalization". Without knowing the dimensions even FFTs will be unfeasable. Are you allowed to tell, how that data has been created?